# Need to gain space between two adjacent rows

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

On bootstrap 3,I can't make the layout how I want to and I can't see why.

My HTML :

```
        <div class="container">
           <div id="row1" class="row">
         <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-push-8 col-md-4 col-md-push-8 col-sm-push-8 col-sm-4">
           <div class="round"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-pull-4 col-md-8 col-md-pull-4 col-sm-8 col-sm-pull-4 intro-text">
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor</p>
         </div>
       </div>
       <div id="row2" class="row">
         <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
           <div class="round"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 intro-text">
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor</p>
         </div>
       </div>
       </div>


My CSS :

    #row1 {
      opacity:0.3;
      background-color: red;
    }

    #row2 {
    opacity:0.3;
    background-color: yellow;
    }
    .intro-text {
     text-align:center;
    }
    .round {
     background:#bfd70e;
     border-radius:50%;
     width:160px;
     height:160px;
     border:2px solid #679403; 
     margin:0 auto;
     }
     @media(min-width:767px) {
      .intro-text {
      margin-top:60px;
      }
     #row2 {
     margin-top:-15px;
     }  
}
```

I want to keep the same structure as the first JS fiddle but gain some space by making the row 2 over the first one. So I tried a margin-top but it break all the structure, I don't know why.

This is JS fiddle without :

```
#row2 {
     margin-top:-15px;
     }
```

[JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7urbw4kq/)

This is JS fiddle with

```
#row2 {
         margin-top:-15px;
         }
```

[JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/584wcaa5/)

How do I fix that ?

Comment: Why are you using -15px, that is pulling it down.  I used just "15px" and got what I think you're looking for:  https://jsfiddle.net/584wcaa5/1/

Comment: Please erase your answer as it's absolutely not my need. thanks

Comment: I think there is a reason you now have 3 downvotes to your question, and my answer isn't the problem.  You aren't being clear in the help you need.

Comment: Whatever. Now you understood my question maybe you can answer it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the elements are positioned statically, therefore colliding with the elements above it.

If you give your second row `position:absolute` it should stop it colliding with the elements as the position is set regardless of what other elements are doing.
https://jsfiddle.net/584wcaa5/2/

Comment: This is not working as it's making a weird gap on large and middle size screens. The grid system seems to be broken.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure on what you're exactly trying to achieve. Can you mock it up in paint or something?

Comment: I need what you've done on JS fiddle, put the second row over the first one to gain some space. But if you enlarge the screen you will see that the width of the row two is not as large as the row 1. It looks like the absolute positioning is breaking the 12 columns system.

Comment: I need to overlay the row 1 with the row 2

Answer (score 1):

Change your:

```
margin-top: -15px;
```

to:

```
margin-top: 15px;
```

Otherwise you're pulling it down.

https://jsfiddle.net/584wcaa5/1/

Comment: That is not my need. I need to gain space by making the row 2 over the first one. Please read carefully next time before make -1.

Comment: Here is what you said, in english: "I want to keep the same structure as the first JS fiddle but gain some space by making the row 2 over the first one".. you said GAIN space.. positive margin will make you GAIN space, if that isn't what you needed, maybe you need to ask your question more carefully.

Comment: As @maulzal said, you have to be more specific.. So you want to overlay `#row1` by `#row2`?